# Symbol’s function definition is void: libxml-parse-html-region

Tags: pip-requirements

When I open a pip file (`requirements.txt`), `pip freeze > requirements.txt`, I get following error message:

```
error in process filter: pip-requirements-callback: Symbol’s function definition is void: libxml-parse-html-region
error in process filter: Symbol’s function definition is void: libxml-parse-html-region
```

In my config file I am using `pip-requirements-mode-hook`

```
(if (not (package-installed-p 'pip-requirements))
    (progn
      (package-install 'pip-requirements)))

(add-hook 'pip-requirements-mode-hook #'pip-requirements-auto-complete-setup)
```

How can I fix it?

---

The way I build emacs:

```bash
dpkg -l | grep emacs | awk '{print $2}' | xargs -n1 sudo apt-get purge -y
mkdir -p ~/tools && cd ~/tools
git clone git://git.savannah.gnu.org/emacs.git && cd emacs
./autogen.sh
./configure --with-x-toolkit=yes --with-x-toolkit=no --with-native-compilation
make -j$(nproc)
sudo mkdir -p /opt/ss
sudo rm -f /opt/ss/*
sudo ln -s ~/tools/emacs/lib-src/emacsclient /opt/ss/
sudo ln -s ~/tools/emacs/src/emacs /opt/ss/
```

Comment: It seems that your emacs is not built with `libxml`: this is a C function.

Comment: I added the way I build native-emacs. I am not sure how can I built it with `libxml`

Comment: In the emacs directory, do `./configure --help`. You probably need to add `--with-libxml` to your command line. Or maybe `--with-xml2`, I don't really remember. And you might to install the `libxml` packages (devel as well)

Comment: Could I use both `--with-libxml` and `--with-xml2`?

Comment: there is only `LIBXML2_CFLAGS C compiler flags for LIBXML2, overriding pkg-config` in the --help section

Comment: OK - just try it and see if it works.

Comment: `--with-libxml` flag does not exist,  I have tried with `--with-xml2` seems like it solved it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With the help of @NickD s comment I was able to solve this problem as follows:

```
$ ./configure --help | grep "LIBXML2"
LIBXML2_CFLAGS
            C compiler flags for LIBXML2, overriding pkg-config
LIBXML2_LIBS
            linker flags for LIBXML2, overriding pkg-config
```

---

I configure emacs with `--with-xml2` flag doing:

```bash
./configure --with-xml2 --with-x-toolkit=yes --with-x-toolkit=no --with-native-compilation 
make -j$(nproc)
```